# How to add a new main property to a card in Dulst?

Tags: css, rules

In Dulst game engine, how to add new property besides Atk and Health.

1. It needs to be displayed on the card's full info display upon hovering
2. It needs to be displayed on the card's container when played on board.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to admin-gameplay, enter the new property name, let's call it Armor in this case. Doing this allows the system to know there's a new property, but it won't display it until you specify it in CSS
   [image: Check screenshot]
2. In your test play, enter /a editCSS in chat box to call out CSS editor, locate code like

```
#cardFullInfo .cardDisplayInner
.cardFullInfo .cardDisplayInner
```

if you scroll down you can see code like

```
        [data-name='cost']
          top 10px
          left 10px
          border 3px solid costColor
        [data-name='atk']
          top 294px
          left 10px
          border 3px solid atkColor
```

you can copy the code below the section, and modify it like

```
       [data-name='cost']
         top 10px
         left 10px
         border 3px solid costColor
       [data-name='atk']
         top 294px
         left 10px
         border 3px solid atkColor

       [data-name='armor']
         top 294px
         left 10px
         border 3px solid yellow
```

You can change the parameter beside top, left, and border to control how the property should look like, just remember to keep indentation consistent. You should see the property coming up if you have cards with armor property.

This will give your card ability to show the property upon hovering.

3. If you want to make the property visible when it's played on board, you should also change its code in container.
   Locate code like

```
/*
 * Play Interface. 
 */

#playContainer
  .card
    box-shadow none
```

If you scroll down, you can see again similar code like

```
      &[data-name="cost"]
        statStyles()
        top .5rem
        left .5rem
        border 1px solid costColor

      &[data-name="atk"]
        statStyles()
        bottom .5rem
        left .5rem
        border 1px solid atkColor
```

Try copy the code again and modify it as step 2.